# Django makemigrations thrown an error if I add a custom model (Tenant) with app_label='auth'

Tags: python, django

This is the model that I have

```
class Tenant(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "auth"
```

When I makemigrations in a new venv or run pytest. I always get an error saying

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration
> nqm_core.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node
> ('auth', '0013_tenant')

I tried the following ways to resolve this issue

1. Remove migrations files and re migrate
2. Fake migrations with zero and then re migrate
3. Create new database and migrate
4. Update django and migrate
5. Create new venv and migrate

None of the above ways worked. The issue got resolved only after I removed the app_label from class Meta for that model. Also I tried removing dependency in the initial migration file but the DB won't migrate at all.

Is this a bug or is there a certain way with which I have to run the migration
Currently, I only use the following commands

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: You can try changing the [`MIGRATION_MODULES` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#migration-modules) for the `auth` app and bring all its migrations to some app of your own. Anyway I advice you not to do this. For what reason would you even need your own model to be in the `auth` app? It's not like having it their would benefit you anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Django has default built-in app with name [auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/), which handles such models like `User`, `Permission` and others.

The easiest solution for you will be to use another `app_label`

Comment: Yes exactly, I want my custom model to be under auth. Using another app_label defeats the purpose of solving the issue.

Comment: @Vaibhav that's not a great idea. Moreover I don't think that's possible. Django project evolves and new migrations under built-in `auth` app will definitely appear.
So even if you would be able to do what you want (extend build-in `auth` app) - in future you would definitely face a lot of problems.
So I would suggest not to do that and instead rename your app to `tenants` or `users`: whatever fits best for you

Comment: Yeah. I guess. Thanks for the insight